# Feedback on my first prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, security, prepared-statement, sql-injection

I've just completed my first prepared statement, converted to using them for security reasons. I've tested it and it works however I am looking for feedback (constructive criticism welcomed) regarding the code itself although I understand it 's fairly basic. Also, I have a few queries:

1. Am I correct in saying you do not require using `mysqli_escape_string` if you use prepared statements?
2. Will using the `mysqli_stmt_get_result` function cut down on the amount of writing I have to do and be as effective?
3. Is using `mysqli_stmt_close` necessary? Am I correct saying that without using this function I will not be able to create another prepared statement within that script?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
//prepared statement example
include 'database.php';
$query = "SELECT ID FROM users WHERE email = ?";
$email = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$statement = mysqli_stmt_init($connect);

mysqli_stmt_prepare($statement, $query);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, 's', $email);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $id);
mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement);

echo $id;
?>
```

Comment: Head over to [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for questions like that. SO is not quite the right place for it.

Comment: Neither on the dead site of CodeReview you will get a valuable feedback. Stalemate. Go on, review your code yourself.

Answer (score 2):

> Am I correct in saying you do not require using mysqli_escape_string if you use prepared statements?

Yes. It's bad sign you're asking it - means you don't clearly understand how does [all that mess works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8265319/285587).

> Will using the mysqli_stmt_get_result function cut down on the amount of writing I have to do and be as effective?

Yes. But here are bad news: is is not always supported. So, on some installations it won't work.

> Is using mysqli_stmt_close necessary? Am I correct saying that without using this function I will not be able to create another prepared statement within that script?

Why, no.
You can simply recreate another prepared statement into this variable.

BTW, it'd strongly recommentd to use [PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) over mysqli. It's way more consistent and user-friendly.
Just try to bind an array for use in `IN()` operator and see.

After all, it takes 2 times less code:

```
$stm = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stm->execute(array($email));
$id = $stm->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would use PDO however it's not supported by my web host provider. What did you mean by "You can simply recreate another prepared statement into this variable." - I don't quite follow.